# Random synchronization error on SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

We can send mails across the network from 1 server to another via a centralized smtp server. However, the we get a synchronization error on the server randomly.

So for example if we send a simple mail 6 times the 3rd one fails with a synchronization error. When we look at the network packet we have

RCPT TO: abc@company.com

C:QUIT -- This for some reason is called before the smtp server processes the request.

[image]
Any clues why this with happen.

Comment: You'll need to give us more details on your setup. I've never heard the word `synchronization` used in relation to SMTP. What exactly is being synchronized and how?

Comment: Added image, please check image in question.

Comment: Are you waiting for the "220 - SMTP Service ready" before attempting to send a message? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264673/554-smtp-synchronization-error-with-exim4-and-my-code

Comment: It looks to me as if `172.23.18.199` is taking a long time handling the recipient address validation, as seen by the delay at the `RCPT TO` request. You need to provide the server log of the transaction from `172.23.18.199`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in your log,

your server at xx.18.199 did not answer the RCPT TO: in 30s,
so a timeout must be setup at the xx.31.37  client which makes it send a QUIT after 30s without answer.

The obvious fix is to **increase the timeout on the client side**.

The less obvious fix is to find out why it takes so long to process the RCPT TO:.
Maybe your **directory** is very slow ?

If you provide more details about your configuration and the email addresses which cause a response time greater than 30s it will certainly be possible to dig further and find out what's happening.